# html form POST request HTTP 404 error on Netlify

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, server

I am using a node.js server on Netlify. I made a post request from html form, but it doesn't work on the server. However, when I tried it locally, it works. What would be the problem?

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.send("good");
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="/api">
      <input name="name" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I tried it locally, it works fine. But when I tried it on netlify server, it made a 404 error.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=hello
```

result: good

```
POST http://test-k.netlify.app/api
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=hello
```

result: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found